# Parsing nested elements within a JSON using c++

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Im using alphavantage to get some data on stock indicators, the data is returned as a JSON type file that looks like this (the first 20 or so lines)

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "AAPL",
        "2: Indicator": "Simple Moving Average (SMA)",
        "3: Last Refreshed": "2022-01-06 20:00:00",
        "4: Interval": "1min",
        "5: Time Period": 10,
        "6: Series Type": "open",
        "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Technical Analysis: SMA": {
        "2022-01-06 20:00": {
            "SMA": "172.8710"
        },
        "2022-01-06 19:59": {
            "SMA": "172.8590"
        },
        "2022-01-06 19:58": {
            "SMA": "172.8390"
        },
        "2022-01-06 19:57": {
            "SMA": "172.8200"
        },
        "2022-01-06 19:56": {
            "SMA": "172.8020"
        },
        "2022-01-06 19:55": {
            "SMA": "172.7800"
        },
```

now I need to access the values "172.8710" etc. i tried iterating through it like this

```
for (auto it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); it++)
            for (auto& elem : j["Technical Analysis: SMA"])
                y.push_back(elem["2022-01-06 20:00"]);
```

y is a vector of floats i initialised earlier

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "172.7800" in that JSON is a string, not a float number. You have to use std::stof(elem["2022-01-06 20:00"]).

Comment: Do you also mean `elem["SMA"]`?

Comment: yup but to get to elem["SMA"] i have to go through the whole tree right?

Comment: No, that's what your second for loop is doing?